# How to set an image's alt-text with pandoc for docx conversion

Tags: pdf, accessibility, docx, pandoc

When exporting to docx, `pandoc` sets the image label as its caption. Is there a way to set an alt-text different from the caption?

## Context

We generate Markdown documents that we want to convert to PDF using Pandoc.

I installed BasicTeX and made some tests with the following markdown:

```
# This is the title

This is a paragraph.

![This is an image](image.jpg)

This is another paragraph.
```

You can [download the file here](https://files.zenhub.io/56d82f934a3277515ee280eb).

Converting this code using Pandoc results in [this PDF file](https://files.zenhub.io/56d82fdc4a3277515ee280ed).

As I'm working for an accessibility consultancy, I first checked the PDF file using [PDF Accessibility Checker 2](http://www.access-for-all.ch/en/pdf-lab/pdf-accessibility-checker-pac.html), and the results are devastating:

[image: PAC2 results]

[image: More results]

So I tried a workaround by [exporting to Microsoft Docx](https://files.zenhub.io/56d831044a3277515ee280f1) (which is highly accessible when the correct document styles are used).

And from there I exported to PDF using [AccessPDF](https://www.axes4.com/axespdf-for-word-overview.html), and here's [the resulting PDF file](https://files.zenhub.io/56d831574a3277515ee280f9)

When checked using PAC2, this is the result:

[image: Results]

Much better, but there's a missing alternative text for an image! So it seems that the alternative text is used as `caption` of the `figure` (the same way it's done in HTML), and while in the HTML export the `alt`-Tag is set properly, in Docx the alternative text is left away.

How can we fix this? In fact, when there's a caption, the image itself should **not** have the same text as `alt`-text again, which means: the way it's exported to HTML is not perfect. So: how much control do we have in markdown to specify specifically the `caption` and `alt` contents?

Answer (score 3):

From the [pandoc readme](http://pandoc.org/README.html#images):

> An image occurring by itself in a paragraph will be rendered as a figure with a caption. (In LaTeX, a figure environment will be used; in HTML, the image will be placed in a div with class figure, together with a caption in a p with class caption.) The image’s alt text will be used as the caption.
>
> ```
> ![This is the caption](/url/of/image.png)
> ```

Update: I see you've created an [issue about this](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2754). Indeed, for some reason, the [docx writer currently uses the title text instead of the alt text](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/20170c328f12fc0214c2c50d14c8f7d03ee05e70/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Docx.hs#L1157). Not sure whether this is intended behaviour or not. Meanwhile, you can use the title text, as in:

```
![alt text](foo.jpg "title text")
```

---

Concerning accessibility: pandoc per default uses LaTeX (you can choose between a few engines) to generate PDFs, but indeed unfortunately LaTeX [isn't known to generate very accessible PDFs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261537/a-guide-on-how-to-produce-accessible-pdf-files). Maybe ConTeXt is better?

```
$ pandoc -t context -o mydoc.tex input.md
$ context mydoc.tex
```